# Why are Render Result and Viewer Node listed as drop down options for Texture sources?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

To reiterate the question: Why are Render result and Viewer Node outputs listed in the drop down options for texture sources in the Image Textures for both Blender Render and Cycles?

I have tried them as possible sources, and they are not functional as a source, even though in an ideal situation they could be used as adjustment or compositing previews for texture painting tasks. [image: viewer node as input texture]

Comment: That editor is called *UV **& Image** Editor* not texture editor. They are not being listed as texture sources, simply as possible image preview source. Weather you use them for unwrapping over or not is up to you, though it might seem to make little sense.

Comment: What is your question? How to change this?

Comment: No, all images in Blender are treated as textures - I know this from extensive study of the texture paint work flow. My point is that if an option is not to be used or is unavailable it is greyed out and not capable of being selected. If it is only to be used as an option in the UV Image Editor, then any reference in the the Materials tab should be greyed out as not assignable. This had to have been by design since it was carried over from Blender Render to Cycles. My question is to WHY if it is not meant to be used - better to eliminate the option if not usable.

Comment: May be a bug, or an oversight by the developers. Who knows?

Comment: That is my hope, that by posting here in Stack that the question will be seen by devs and possibly addressed either as something that needs a bug report filed or as a problem to address in 2.8 series.